# AttributeError: 'DatasetAutoFolds' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: split, attributeerror, collaborative-filtering

[image]

the code s from a recommendation engine using surprise module, i can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: This link has another way of doing it ( by using KFold)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305393/svd-has-no-split-attribute

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you objective is, you can use the `cross_validation` method and it will perform the splits automatically for you.  Example: `cross_validate(algorithm_to_use, data, measures=['RMSE'], cv=5)...` The `cv=5` tells the cross validation iterator how to split the data.

See documentation on [Cross validation](http://[https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model_selection.html#surprise.model_selection.validation.cross_validate]).

You can also [explore the model selection package for what you need](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model_selection.html#surprise.model_selection.split.train_test_split).

Context is important when trying to help you find a solution.

Comment: any idea about how can i specify algorithm_to_use. [this](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/algobase.html#surprise.prediction_algorithms.algo_base.AlgoBase) link does not help much. Better if you have link with example

Comment: This link has another way of doing it by using KFold [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305393/svd-has-no-split-attribute)